# How to fit title in jquerymobile dialog's Title bar?

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jquery mobile for web app development , I used jQM-SimpleDialog ([jQM-SimpleDialog](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/)) to show message to user. My message string truncated. How to show complete sentence?
I got this output in iPhone [image]

But I want to show this message : "Please fill the form properly."

Thanks,

-- regeint

Answer (score 1):

What's cutting-off the title are the margins on the left and right. They are set to be large enough to not allow overlapping of the title and any buttons in the header.

You can try some CSS like this:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-header h1 {
    margin-left  : 30px;
    margin-right : 0px;
}
```

This may un-center the title but I haven't used the `jQM-SimpleDialog` plugin so I'm not sure what it adds to the mix.

Here is a demonstration of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/Y75dE/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through CSS.

Assign a Class to the div/dialog.

Ex:

```
<div class="mydialog"/>
```

Put the below css snippet code in the css file and include this in header.

Add a class to the CSS file.

```
.mydialog  {
    margin-left  : 20px;
    margin-right : 1px;
}
```

This should help you, customize the left,right as per your requirement.

Comment: This is a jQuery Mobile specific question, where the element in discussion is already target-able through the jQuery Mobile CSS schema. Adding another class will work but is not necessary.